# How to keep live streaming play in background

Tags: android, cordova, angular, ionic2, audio-streaming

How can i keep the live stream play in the background even if i closed the app and show the mini-player in the notification area with some controls in an `ionic2` app.

Currently i'm streaming using the `HTML5 Audio API`

```
constructor() {
    this.url = "http://streamer-provider.com:8080/Live";
    this.stream = new Audio(this.url);
    this.stream.play();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build a Service:

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html